# Why search.maven.org does not return results when I search for the term "postg" or "mysq"?

Tags: rest, maven

I want to know why the `search.maven.org` site doesn't return any results when I search for the term "postg" or "mysq".

Example: `http://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=postg&rows=20&wt=json`

The NetBeans "Add dependency..." dialog works well when searching for those terms. (I'm pretty sure it is using another REST API)

Is there a very good reason why `search.maven.org` does not return results and only word suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`search.maven.org` performs the search based on the query parameter you gave. Since there are no artifacts having a groupId or artifactId of `postg`, the results are empty.

But you can use the wildcard `*` to achieve what you want:

```
http://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=postg*&rows=20&wt=json
```

This search URL will return all the artifacts whose groupId or artifactId start with `postg`.

If you want to search only on the artifactId starting with `postg`, you can use the following URL:

```
http://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=a:postg*&core=gav&rows=20&wt=json
```

or on both the groupId and artifactId starting with `postg`:

```
http://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:postg*+AND+a:postg*&core=gav&rows=20&wt=json
```

The Rest API is documented on [this page](http://search.maven.org/#api).

Comment: What does the core=gav parameter do? Are there any more undocumented parameters to refine queries?

Comment: Here's the latest link for REST API documentation https://central.sonatype.org/search/rest-api-guide/